# How do I correctly position my footer?

Tags: css, position

I want to position my footer at the baseline of my #wrapper but all I seem to be able to do is get the footer positioned below the wrapper. Can someone please tell me why this is happening?

Also, if someone sees a problem with how I have this currently designed and has a better way, I'm open to any suggestions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>sd</title>
<style type="text/css">
  html, body {
  width:100%;
  background:brown;
  border:0px solid red;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  }
  #wrapper {
  width:1220px;
  height:750px;
  padding:0;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:#ccc;
  border:3px solid white;
  }
  #header {
  background-color:#aaa;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  padding:0;
  margin:0 auto 0 auto;
  border:0px solid;
  }
  #content {
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  height:649px;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  border:0px solid;
  }
  #cell-left {
  background-color:#bbb;
  float:left;
  width:200px;
  height:100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  border:0px solid;
  }
  #cell-right {
  float:right;
  width:1010px;
  height:100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  border:0px solid;
  }
  #footer {
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  height:25px;
  padding:4px;
  margin:0;
  text-align:center;
  border:1px solid;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content">
      <div id="cell-left">dsssd</div>
      <div id="cell-right">dsssd</div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">sdsd</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like you are using a lot of conflicting styles, and why a `float: left;` on an element that is 100% wide?

Comment: @Justus, because I don't know any better. :) I'm trying to leave tables in the past and learn a little css. I thought that float was always needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the fixed height on `#wrapper` (`height:750px`), and [clear the floated elements](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) inside `#wrapper` properly.

The easiest way to do this is to add `overflow: hidden` to `#wrapper`.

**See:** http://jsbin.com/iciwo6

The changed CSS:

```
#wrapper {
overflow:hidden;
width:1220px;
padding:0;
margin:0 auto;
background:#ccc;
border:3px solid white;
}
```

Comment: Thank you thirtydot, that works. Is there a reason why the border of my footer extends past the right part of the page?

Comment: The reason is that you've specified `width: 100%` on `#footer`. Borders are added onto that width, so the width of the footer *including* the borders is greater than the space available. To fix that, remove `float:left` and `width: 100%`, and add `clear: both` to `#footer`. You don't need `overflow: hidden` any longer. See: http://jsbin.com/iciwo6/2

Comment: Thanks thirtydot. I'm confused, from where should I remove the `float:left` and `width:100%`?

Comment: I got it... Thank you thirtydot!

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned the wrapper height 750 that is showing problem.Just make it clear and give `height:auto`
You have given

```
 header:  `height:100px;` 
content: height:649px;
```

so it is taking almost 750px .so there is no space for footer.so it is coming just below the wrapper.So try to give height:auto.